# How do I add OctahedronGeometry to the editor?

Tags: three.js

I am using the editor as a standalone app and would like there to be an option in the `Add` menu to place an octahedron into my scene. I thought adding `three.module.js` to the editor would work but unfortunately it does not.

There doesn't seem to be many questions here on SO about my issue either, which doesn't give me a lot of confidence that a solution is out there. Still, if you have an idea, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an octahedron:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 4, 2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( sphere );
```

https://threejs.org/docs/api/geometries/SphereGeometry.html

In the editor, you can select "Sphere" in the add menu, then click the "Geometry" tab on the right to change the Width Segments to 4 and the Height Segments to 2.

Comment: I didn't realize you could make them from spheres. Thanks a lot!